# How can I count the number of http requests outside of a docker container?

Tags: docker, http, containers, qos

I am new to docker and I hope to monitor some QoS metrics of service in a docker container. Does docker provide some API that I can count the HTTP requests to each container with deploy code inside of the containers?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Docker's only metrics API is the [`/containers/{id}/stats`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerStats) endpoint, and it looks like that only publishes interface-level statistics (generally the total number of bytes that have gone in and out of a container).  That interface doesn't provide port-level or HTTP-level metrics.

You might check to see whether the HTTP framework you're using has metric instrumentation built-in.  If it does, you can use open-source tools like Prometheus and Grafana to collect and display those metrics.

At a technical level, decoding the HTTP stream is trickier than just forwarding packets along, and you need a more involved proxy setup.  If you're using Kubernetes, service meshes like Istio often provide these statistics for you, by running a proxy (Envoy) that handles all traffic; but especially for a small application, instrumenting your own code will be much easier than installing Kubernetes and Istio and trying to deploy there.

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice. I considered the service mesh, but since I am deploying my app on a raspberry pi, I am afraid service mesh may take too much resource.